# How to calculate the genus of a 3 dimensional curve (f(kx,ky,kz)) using the Newton polyhedra?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, genus

Given a plane affine curve $\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}k_x^ik_y^j = 0$, its genus can be calculated as the number of integral points of the interior of the convex hull of $\{(i,j) \mid a_{i,j} \neq 0\}$.

How to extend this formalism (evaluation of genus) for a three-dimensional curve $(\sum_{i,j,l}a_{i,j,l}k_x^ik_y^jk_z^l = 0)$ using Newton Polyhedra ?

For instance, I attach a three-variable polynomial $f(k_x,k_y,k_z)=0$. If we make $k_z=0$, we obtain the Newton polygon and its interior points. We find the genus of the curve accordingly. Now, my question is, how to relate the genus and newton polyhedra for a three-dimensional curve?

The polynomial is.
[$k_x^2 - k_y^2 - 3 k_x^4 k_z - 6 k_x^2 k_y^2 k_z - 3 k_y^4 k_z + k_z^3 - 
 6 k_x^2 k_z^3 - 6 k_y^2 k_z^3 - 3 k_z^5 + 6 k_x^2 k_z m + 6 k_y^2 k_z m + 
 6 k_z^3 m - 3 k_z m^2 + 
 i (k_x^6 + 2 k_x k_y + 3 k_x^4 k_y^2 + 3 k_x^2 k_y^4 + k_y^6 - 3 k_x^2 k_z^2 + 
    3 k_x^4 k_z^2 - 3 k_y^2 k_z^2 + 6 k_x^2 k_y^2 k_z^2 + 3 k_y^4 k_z^2 - 
    3 kz^4 + 3 kx^2 kz^4 + 3 ky^2 kz^4 + kz^6 - 3 kx^4 m - 
    6 k_x^2 k_y^2 m - 3 k_y^4 m + 3 k_z^2 m - 6 k_x^2 k_z^2 m - 
    6 k_y^2 k_z^2 m - 3 k_z^4 m + 3 k_x^2 m^2 + 3 k_y^2 m^2 + 3 k_z^2 m^2 - 
    m^3)$.]

Attached are the Newton Polygon [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s5D9.jpg) and curve [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEp0N.jpg) for $k_z=0$.

[Newton polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s5D9.jpg)